# python: skimage.transform.AffineTransform rotation center

Tags: python, rotation, scikit-image

I am trying to use skimage in python to rotate an image, in opencv, [it seems I can do](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html):

```
cv.GetRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale, mapMatrix)
```

where center is the Center of the rotation in the source image.

in skimage the respective transformation seems to be [skimage.transform.AffineTransform](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html):

```
skimage.transform.AffineTransform(matrix=None, scale=None, rotation=None, shear=None, translation=None)
```

But I cannot how to define the center of the rotation.... Is there away to define the rotation center in this (or maybe there is another skimage method?)

I have checked the web and the manuals, finding nothing so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently possible by combining the following transformations:

1. Shift the image so that the centre is around the origin
2. Rotate with N degrees
3. Shift the image back

However, a single parameter would make this much easier!  Would you please file an issue on GitHub so that we can implement this?

In the meantime, the code:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import transform
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = data.chelsea()

shift_y, shift_x = np.array(image.shape[:2]) / 2.
tf_rotate = transform.SimilarityTransform(rotation=np.deg2rad(30))
tf_shift = transform.SimilarityTransform(translation=[-shift_x, -shift_y])
tf_shift_inv = transform.SimilarityTransform(translation=[shift_x, shift_y])

image_rotated = transform.warp(image, (tf_shift + (tf_rotate + tf_shift_inv)).inverse)

plt.imshow(image_rotated)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've added an issue here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1166

Comment: It must be noted that the issue was NOT fixed for Similarity/AffineTransform. The only transformation that was fixed is Rotation.

Comment: We are not planning on "fixing" it for the individuals transforms: those don't have centers, as such.  Instead, you can use the procedure outlined above.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the difference. A Rotation transform is just a special case of an Affine transform. You could also use the procedure outlined above with the Rotation transform, yet a center parameter _is_ provided for Rotation. 
All transforms assume that the origin of the transform must be the (0,0) of the image. You could easily have a parameter to change that assumption as needed.

Comment: I guess I think of `rotate` as a convenience function, and the Transform objects themselves as more low-level primitives.  But, I see that we already provide initialization from parameters for at least Affine and Similarity, so yes—we could add it.  It's not a high priority, but we will review a PR if provided.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge :D. Will try to provide one after the current deadline. I do love that transforms can be composed with `+`, that was a nice surprise.

Answer (score 4):

The image center in Stefan's answer seems not correct, here comes a corrected version of his code

```
from skimage import transform
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.zeros([21, 21])
image[10,:] = 1
image[10,10] = 5
image[7, 10] = 1

shift_y, shift_x = (np.array(image.shape)-1) / 2.
tf_rotate = transform.SimilarityTransform(rotation=np.deg2rad(60))
tf_shift = transform.SimilarityTransform(translation=[-shift_x, -shift_y])
tf_shift_inv = transform.SimilarityTransform(translation=[shift_x, shift_y])
image_rotated = transform.warp(image, (tf_shift + (tf_rotate + tf_shift_inv)).inverse, order = 3)


plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(image_rotated)
plt.show()

print "original image maximum at: ", np.unravel_index(np.argmax(image), image.shape)
print "rotated image maximum at : ", np.unravel_index(np.argmax(image_rotated), image_rotated.shape)
```

original image maximum at:  (10, 10)
rotated image maximum at :  (10, 10)